# laravel route to a specific url

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-routing

I want to create a route in laravel 4 with this parameters

```
$options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => 'images_upload'];
$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload_handler.php', $options);
```

which means a route that point to this $upload_url. createUploadUrl do a post at upload_handler.php and stores data to gs bucket. My problem is that post isn't performed because upload_url  should be specified at routes. How can I do this?

upload_handler.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_FILES);
?>
```

view

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'upload_handler','files' => true)) }}
{{ Form::file('file') }}
<br>
{{ Form::submit('Add Photo', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary' )) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

route

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::post('upload_handler', function($upload_url = null) {
        $options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => 'images_upload'];
        $upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload_handler.php', $options);
        return $upload_url;
    });
});
```

but this just returns the url. How to do post?

In pure php the code is:

```
require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';

use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

$options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => 'images_upload'];
$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload_handler.php', $options);
?>
<div class="body">
    <form action="<?php echo $upload_url ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="uploaded_files" size="40">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @Antonio Carlos Ribeiro do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague I'm afraid but I think what you're after is `Redirect::to`. This will allow you to redirect the `post` request to the URL generated by the method on the `CloudStorageTools` class.

```
return Redirect::to($upload_url);
```

Comment: i just added the original code in php, which I want to transform in laravel. The idea is that I want to perform a post at the first argument in createUploadUrl method and also save the file in GS which is done automatically. $upload_url is generated and now how to perform a post at it first argument?

Comment: any idea how to do this? I am stuck